# Accessing xml theme's parent

Tags: android, android-theme

I have a number of Themes defined in my Android project, all inheriting from different parents. Is there any way to programmatically check what the parent of a theme is in my code, perhaps through attributes?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

As a work-around I have declared another string attribute, and then in every sub-theme I have set this attribute to be the name of the parent, which I can then access in my code and get the theme id from the string. But it seems redundant to be effectively declaring the parent twice in every theme.